# ng-init does not call ng-change function

Tags: angularjs

I am new in angular js and i have a an issue like i have a radio button on which click i want to show a div having text boxes along with the refilled values in it.

```
<div class="step-option">
    <input type="radio" name="delivery-type" id="mailToMeTab" value="UserAddress"
        ng-model="UserAddress" 
        ng-init="isShown('UserAddress',userInfo)" 
        ng-click="isShown('UserAddress',userInfo)" 
        ng-checked="true">
    <label for="mailToMeTab" class="textStyle">
    Mail me a Paper Card first <span class="lightcolor">(via U.S. Postal Service)</span>
    </label>
</div>
<div class="col-md-6" id="idUserAddress">
    <h4>Enter your address</h4>
    <input type="text" required placeholder="Your Name" class="form-control" ng-model="cName" />
    <div class="clr10"></div>
        <textarea rows="2" type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="cAddress" placeholder="Street Address"></textarea>
        <div class="clr10"></div>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="City" ng-model="cCity">
        <div class="clr10"></div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-5">
            <select class="form-control" ng-model="selectedState" required ng-options="s as s.stateName for s in states">
                <option value="">Select State</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-7">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Zip" ng-model="cZipCode">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-6" id="idRecipientAddress" @*ng-show="isShown('RecipientAddress')"*@>
    <h4>Enter the recipient's address</h4>
    @if (WebSecurity.IsAuthenticated){
        <input type="text" placeholder="Your Name" class="form-control" typeahead="friend as friend.name +'<br>'+ friend.address +'<br>'+ friend.city for friend in Savedfriends| filter: $viewValue|orderBy:'name'| limitTo:2" ng-model="rName" typeahead-on-select="Filltextboxes(rName)" />
    }
    else{
        <input type="text" placeholder="Your Name" class="form-control" ng-model="rName" />
    }
    <div class="clr10"></div>
        <textarea rows="2" type="text" placeholder="Street Address" class="form-control" ng-model="rAddress"></textarea>
        <div class="clr10"></div>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="City" ng-model="rCity">
        <div class="clr10"></div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-5">
            <select class="form-control" ng-model="rselectedState" ng-options="s as s.stateName for s in states">
            <option value="">Select State</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-7">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Zip" ng-model="rZipCode">
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
cardRepository.getUser().then(function (details) {
    $scope.userInfo = details;
});

 $scope.isShown = function (content, userInfo) {
    debugger;
    //return content === $scope.content;
    if (userInfo.firstName != null && userInfo.lastName != null) {
        $scope.cName = userInfo.firstName + ' ' + userInfo.lastName;
    }
    else {
        $scope.cName = "";
    }

    if (userInfo.address != null) {
        $scope.cAddress = userInfo.address;
    }
    else {
        $scope.cAddress = "";
    }
    if (userInfo.city != null) {
        $scope.cCity = userInfo.city;
    }
    else {
        $scope.cCity = "";
    }
    if (userInfo.zipCode != null) {
        $scope.cZipCode = userInfo.zipCode;
    }
    else {
        $scope.cZipCode = "";
    }
    if (userInfo.state != null) {
        $scope.selectedState = $scope.states[parseInt(userInfo.state) - 1];
    }
    else {
        $scope.selectedState = $scope.states;
    }
    if (content == "UserAndRecipientAddress") {
        $('#idUserAddress').show();
        $('#idRecipientAddress').show();
    }
    else {
        $('#idUserAddress').show();
        $('#idRecipientAddress').hide();
    }

};
```

at ng-init it does show userinfo value but at page load it has values so it never display refilled text boxes at page load, please help me out in this and suggest if i am wrong somewhere.

Comment: Are you sure that `userInfo` has a value when `ng-init` fires? I don't see anything that would guarantee that it does. I also don't understand why you're putting those events on a seemingly unrelated radio button.

Comment: yes i see it using debugger it has a object with values but as soon as ng-init call scope.userinfo value lost

Comment: @ManishaAgarwal: can you add your code of HTML and Controller?

Comment: Again, I have to ask: Is `userInfo` assigned a value _before_, or _after_ the `isShown()` function runs?

Comment: first getUser() function calls and gets the userInfo value after that isShown() function gets call i used debugger on page load to check it

Comment: Hi I found that when i use $scope.A = '007'; and pass it to the ng-init="isShown('UserAddress',A)" i am getting value of A but when i use ng-init="isShown('UserAddress',userInfo)" userInfo gets " " only at the debugger.